# Why is the kth cohomology group of the DM-compactification of the moduli space of curves pure of weight k?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hodge-theory

I'm trying to understand the paper

Arbarello, Enrico, Cornalba, Maurizio,
Calculating cohomology groups of moduli spaces of curves via algebraic geometry. 
Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. No. 88 (1998), 97–127 (1999).

At the very top of page 103 (of the journal; this is the 7th page of the paper) they assert without proof that $H^k(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,p})$ is pure of weight $k$.  I'm not at all an expert in Hodge theory, so I'm probably missing something obvious here, but why is this clear?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_structure and especially the second example in "Examples" on that page.

Comment: @Ari : Yes, but $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,p}$ is *not* smooth; it has singularities along its boundary.

Comment: But it has only quotient singularities, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Gina The DM-stack $\overline { \mathcal M_{g,p}}$ is smooth; see Theorem 2.1 in http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~freixas/Site/Recherche_files/SingARR_arxiv.pdf .

Comment: @Ari : So the whole theory of weights works for stacks?  Is there a down-to-earth reference for that?  I was reading the paper just thinking of the coarse moduli spaces.  Is there a way to see this using from the orbifold perspective, i.e. from the fact that there is a finite orbifold cover that is smooth (such a thing was constructed by de Jong-Pikaart).?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi : You are correct that it only has quotient singularities.  Does this imply that $H^k$ is pure of weight $k$?  I can't find a statement like that in any of the surveys I've consulted, but as I said I am not an expert in this area.

Comment: Gina, yes, the purity follows from Deligne, Theorie de Hodge III, Thm 8.2.4 (iv) + plus the fact that orbifolds are rational homology manifolds. I'm sure it's Peters-Steenbrink also if that is preferable.

Comment: @Gina Yes the whole theory of weights works also for stacks. But a remark is that you can bypass stacks completely in this case, since (as you mention) the spaces $\overline M_{g,n}$ are quotients of a smooth projective variety by a finite group. In general one has for rational cohomology $H^\bullet(X/G) = H^\bullet(X)^G$ ($G$-invariants); when $X$ is an algebraic variety, $H^\bullet(X)^G$ is a sub-Hodge structure of $H^\bullet(X)$ and in particular it is pure if $H^\bullet(X)$ is pure.

Comment: By the way, the fact that $\overline M_{g,n}$ is a quotient of a smooth projective variety by a finite group action was first proven (over the complex numbers) by Looijenga (the paper on "Prym level structures").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me elaborate on my comment, adding some details and references.

The space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g, \, p}$ is an *almost Kähler $V$-manifold*. This means that it has only quotient singularities and admits a bimeromorphic, proper  modification which is a Kähler manifold.

Then the assertion follows by applying the following result, that is Theorem 2.43, p. 57 of Peters-Steenbrink's book *Mixed Hodge Structures.*

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be an almost Kähler $V$-manifold. Then $H^k(X, \, \mathbb{Q})$ admits a pure Hodge structure of weight $k$.